# How to start sparksession in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to change the default memory, executor and core settings of a spark session.
The first code in my pyspark notebook on HDInsight cluster in Jupyter looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName("Juanita_Smith")\
    .config("spark.executor.instances", "2")\
    .config("spark.executor.cores", "2")\
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "2g")\
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "2g")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

On completion, I read the parameters back, which looks like the statement worked
[image]

However if I look in yarn, the setting have indeed not worked.

[image]

[image]

Which settings or commands do I need to make to let the session configuration take effect ?

Thank you for help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the time your notebook kernel has started, the `SparkSession` is already created with parameters defined in a kernel configuration file. To change this, you will need to update or replace the kernel configuration file, which I believe is usually somewhere like `<jupyter home>/kernels/<kernel name>/kernel.json`.

#### Update

If you have access to the machine hosting your Jupyter server, you can find the location of the current kernel configurations using `jupyter kernelspec list`. You can then either edit one of the pyspark kernel configurations, or copy it to a new file and edit that. For your purposes, you will need to add the following arguments to the `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`:

`"PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": "--conf spark.executor.instances=2 --conf spark.executor.cores=2 --conf spark.executor.memory=2g --conf spark.driver.memory=2g"`

Comment: Please note, I am not submitting a job, I am working in Jupyter notebook online during development only and executing one cell at a time. Statement above 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS' does not seem to work in PySpark Jupyter session.

Comment: @JuanitaSmith Ah sorry, that's a bash command to use if you had access to the machine hosting your Jupyter server. I looked a bit more into HDInsight (I'm not familiar with it), and it appears that you don't have direct access to the kernel configs. As I said above, __by the time your kernel is running, the SparkSession is already created__. After this point you can't easily modify the cluster. It appears that on HDInsight, your pyspark kernel just uses whatever is available on the HDInsight cluster you have configured. Can you provide any detail about your cluster configuration?