# How to fix this fatal error while running spark jobs on HDIinsight cluster? Session 681 unexpectedly reached final status 'dead'. See logs:

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

I am running pyspark code on HDIcluster and getting this error:

> The code failed because of a fatal error:     Session 681 unexpectedly
>   reached final status 'dead'. See logs:

I don't have experience in YARN or Hadoop. I tried few links provided in stack overflow. But none of them helped. One strange thing is I was able to run the same code yesterday with out that error.

I just ran this import

`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession`

This is the error I am getting:

```
19/06/21 20:35:35 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: [Fri Jun 21 20:35:35 +0000 2019] Application is Activated, waiting for resources to be assigned for AM.  Details : AM Partition = <DEFAULT_PARTITION> ; Partition Resource = <memory:819200, vCores:240> ; Queue's Absolute capacity = 50.0 % ; Queue's Absolute used capacity = 99.1875 % ; Queue's Absolute max capacity = 100.0 % ; 
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1561149335158
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: https://mmsorderpredhdi.azurehdinsight.net/yarnui/hn/proxy/application_1560840076505_0062/
     user: livy
19/06/21 20:35:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
19/06/21 20:35:35 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-bb63c5f0-7579-4456-b32a-0e643ca97ecc

YARN Diagnostics: 
Application killed by user..
```

Question : Is there something to deal with Queue's absolute used capacity?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the logs to find the exact issue?

Where do I find the log file?

On Azure HDInsight cluster, You may found the livy log by connecting to one of the Head nodes with SSH and downloading a file at this path.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /app-logs/livy/logs-ifile
```

For more details, refer "[Access Apache Hadoop YARN application logs on Linux-based HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-access-yarn-app-logs-linux#yarn-resourcemanager-ui)"

And also, you may refer “[How to start sparksession in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45235515/how-to-start-sparksession-in-pyspark)”.

Hope this helps.